# setting up SummarySE in ddply function of plyr package

Tags: r, plyr, summary

I have a question on summarySE as described in http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/\

While I am setting it up in R studio, I get an error message.

```
> datac <- ddply(data, groupvars,
+ .fun= function(xx, col, na.rm) {
+ c( N= length2(xx[,col], na.rm=na.rm),
+ mean = mean   (xx[,col], na.rm=na.rm),
+ sd   = sd     (xx[,col], na.rm=na.rm)
+ )
+ },
+ measurevar,
+ na.rm
+ )

Error in if (empty(.data)) return(.data) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What does this mean and what do I do?
Thanks

Comment: did you run the whole function or just the portion with ddply?You need to run from summarySE and not from datac.

Comment: yes I ran it from the beginning. error message appears at the ddply